# Target only links that have submenus in selector

Tags: jquery, css

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Discography</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Videography</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to grab the primary links that have submenus in a jquery selector. I don't want to grab the submenu links. I only want the primary links that have submenus.

I tried the selector below but it gives me all of the primary links (Home, Discography, Videography, About).

```
$("#nav > li > a").click(function() {
    alert("click called");
});
```

Instead I only want it to alert when a user clicks on Discography and Videography.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/fym5y6xb/2/)***

```
$("#nav li:has(ul) > a").click(function() {
    alert("click called");
});
```

P.S: The above will work even for deeper nested lists!

Comment: @Roko The click event also alerts on the submenu links which I don't want. I only want it so that it alerts when you click on Discography or Videography

Answer (score 3):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vuc5a8L1/1/) just use .has('ul').length  .. like that

```
$("#nav  li  a").click(function() {
   if($(this).parent().has('ul').length){
      alert("this has submenu");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find if any ul elements exist...

```
$("#nav li").click(function() {
var subs = $('ul')
if($(this).find(subs).length !== 0){
  alert("Click called");
}
});
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZMD/jf478rL0/2/)

**Edit**

"li" and all its children get selected in the code above, here's how to fix that

```
 $("#nav li a").click(function() {
 var subs = $('ul')
 if($(this).parent().find(subs).length!==0){
  alert("Click called");
 }
});
```

edited [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZMD/jf478rL0/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can go this way as well:

```
$( '#nav li a' ).click(function() {

    var submenu = $( this ).find( 'ul' ).length;
    if( submenu > 0 )
    {
        // Your Code Here
    }

});
```